New tag - quantum computing in finance
Would it be possible to introduce new tag quantum-computing-for-finance?
I found some question on this topic, so it seems reasonable to introduce it.
However, I have not enough reputation to create it on my own.

Which questions did you find?

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25827/quantum-computing-for-quantitative-finance/51640#51640   and    https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17604/quantum-mechanics-and-economics-what/27505#27505

I've added the tag to the two linked questions, it now exists.

Thanks. I just added description for the tag.
